# Connecting to splunk server using python script then use this a in robotframework test

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework, splunk

I am new to python and have run in to a problem with the following.
This is a code snippet from the Splunk api, thats used to connect to a splunk server then print the installed apps.

```
import splunklib.client as client

HOST = "server.splunk"
PORT = 8089
USERNAME = "UserABC"
PASSWORD = "Passw000rd"

# Create a Service instance and log in 
service = client.connect(
    host=HOST,
    port=PORT,
    username=USERNAME,
    password=PASSWORD)

# Print installed apps to the console to verify login
for app in service.apps:
    print app.name
```

I've tried it on my system in cmd and it works fine. However I intend to use this function in a Robot Framework test so the function needs to be defined in order to have a keyword I can use. I'm guessing something like the following:

```
import splunklib.client as client

def setServer(HOST, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD):
    HOST = "server.splunk"
    PORT = 8089
    USERNAME = "UserABC"
    PASSWORD = "Passw000rd"
    service = client.connect(host=HOST,port=PORT,username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD)
    for app in service.apps:
       print app.name
    print ("\n")
```

My problem is when I run this nothing is printed to CMD at all. Any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A `print` in Python library is not displayed on the console of Robot Framework, that is the expected behaviour. If you want to check that the piece of code was run and the print was done, check the `log.html` produced by Robot. It should contain your print. Then if you really want to display something on Robot Console, then you have to use [Log To Console](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20To%20Console) keyword from your Robot Test. But as your `print` is in the python lib, you will have to [import BuiltIn lib within your Python code](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-builtin-library). With all that, you should be fine.

Comment: I think you mean log.html

Comment: indeed. Thx. Fixed in my answer.